# Regex to interpret smtlib2 format

Tags: regex, smt-lib

I am trying to figure out a regex that could match results of a program that outputs in the smtlib format. Basically, my data is in the form:

```
 (define-fun X_1 () Int
    281)
 (define-fun X_71 () Int
    104)
 (define-fun X_90 () Int
    21)
 (define-fun X_54 () Int
    250)
etc.
```

Is it possible to write an expression that matches:

```
X_1 (...) 281
X_71 (...) 104
X_90 (...) 21
etc.
```

My current approach is to find individual occurences using `\(define-fun[\w\s]+\)`, then for each occurence, remove `(define-fun`, `Int`, `()` and `)`, and then read the data as all that's left is something like
`1    281`, `71   104`

I'm just wondering if there is a more elegant way of doing this?

Comment: It is not that clear what you need to match. If the format is that strict, you may probably use `\(define-fun\s+(\w+)\s*\([^()]*\)\s*([\w\W]*?)\s*(\d+)\)`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/EUS9vd/1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capture these substrings:

```js
\(define-fun\s+(\S+).*\n\s*(\d+)\)
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/77dthh/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \(                       '('
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  define-fun               'define-fun'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \S+                      non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t, \f,
                             and " ") (1 or more times (matching the
                             most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \n                       '\n' (newline)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \)                       ')'
```